# Can Wishing Ring be applied on side-effects?

Tags: munchkin

Yesterday I was playing Munchkin (the fantasy version) with some friends, and I ended up having my sex changed (I could use some female-only stuff, thou, but that's another story).

Back in topic, when I get sex-changed, I suffer a `-5` penality to my next fight, which I assume lasts until I kill a monster or I suffer his Bad Stuff; either way, I have to actually *fight* him, not just *encounter* him and run away.

Assuming my interpretation is correct, it might be the case where all my buddies try to keep my penality standing as long as possible, by removing monsters in some way (with potions or `charming` spells), thus preventing me from an actual fight.

My question then is: can I use Wishing Ring (which I have obtained after being cursed) to remove the `-5` penality? Because I don't think I can remove the whole `Change Sex` curse after I suffered it in the first place...

Comment: Until you get rid of that -5, you're far too distracted to think of using your wishing ring to get rid of that -5!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is one of those situations that is pretty much up to the table to resolve.  See the interpretation in [this thread](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=76648):

> A Wishing Ring can remove a curse and its effects at anytime.
>
> So things like Big Feet, Tiny Hands and Chicken on your Head can be
>   removed by a wishing ring even though after they have hit and are
>   persistent.
>
> **There is only one exception to this that I know of. Sex Change. The
>   effects of the Sex Change curse can be canceled only at the time that
>   the Curse is played. After it has taken effect the change is
>   permanent. Playing a Wishing Ring afterwards can remove the -5 if you
>   haven't been in combat but it can't revert you back to your original
>   sex.**

But contrast with [this opinion](http://www.helium.com/items/1882706-munchkin-wishing-ring):

> Wishing Rings have one function straight off the card, and that's to
>   get rid of a curse. Whether it's to negate one that's incoming or one
>   that's been lingering for a while, the Wishing Ring will undo any
>   hated curse that would put your character in a detrimental situation.
>   **(Whether or not this applies to a curse that causes a sex change is up
>   to the table in general, so long as it's after the fact.)**

Munchkin isn't the kind of game where the interaction between different cards is always cut-and-dried.  I personally think it would be a bit mean to rule against a Wishing Ring being able to negate a Sex Change's -5 penalty, but it really does depend what kind of vindictive maniacs you have in your group!

Comment: Well, this is a very complete answer, thank you. Just to be sure, do you think that my interpretation of *next fight* is correct? BTW, they to avoid me getting rid of the curse because I am a vindicative maniac too ;)

Comment: Actually I think if you run away, it counts as having been in a combat.  You run away because you are in a combat which you are losing... you don't actually run away before you get into combat.

Comment: As thesunneversets is getting at once, the -5 is meant to ruin you just the once. If you can't win because of that -5, then you have to run away, since trying to run away isn't optional and happens when you determine you've lost the fight.